# Annotation to serialize Jackson field as a JSON string (instead of object)

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm working with [Amazon SNS push notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html#mobile-push-send-multiplatform) and they require me to send a payload like:

```json
{ 
  "default": "This is the default message which must be present when publishing a message to a topic. The default message will only be used if a message is not present for 
one of the notification platforms.",     
  "APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"} }",
  "GCM": "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"}}",
  "ADM": "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"}}" 
}
```

I have some classes that look like:

```java
record APS(String alert) {}
record APNS(APS aps) {}
record SNSNotification(
  @JsonProperty("default") String defaultMessage,
  @JsonProperty("APNS") APNS apns
) {}
```

But when I serialize them I get non-insane JSON:

```json
{
  "default": "...",
  "APNS": { "alert": "..." }
}
```

I looked into using `@JsonSerialize(as =  String.class, using = SomeSerializer.class)` but I'm not sure what class to plug in there? `BeanSerializer` didn't like that I'm using a record and nothing else really made sense.

Is there a simple way to do this without pre-serializing the fields?

Answer (score 0):

> I looked into using @JsonSerialize(as =  String.class, using = SomeSerializer.class)

One of the options is to create a custom serializer by extending [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) and override it's `serialize()` method.

One of the arguments of `serialize()` is a `JsonGenerator`, which as it's name suggests allow to generate JSON. You can with go with `JsonGenerator` on pretty low level by specifying manually start/end of a JSON-object (JSON-array), writing field-names, etc., or you can feed a nested object into the `JsonGenerator` as is, depending on whether its default shape satisfies your needs or not.

That's how it might look like (*I wasn't touching "GCM" and "ADM" properties from your JSON because it's unclear where they should come from*).

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SNSNotificationSerializer.class)
record SNSNotification(
    @JsonProperty("default") String defaultMessage,
    @JsonProperty("APNS") APNS apns
) {}

public class SNSNotificationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SNSNotification> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(SNSNotification value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        
        gen.writeStartObject();     // {
        gen.writeStringField("default", value.defaultMessage()); // "default": " ",
        gen.writeFieldName("APNS"); // "APNS" :
        gen.writeStartObject();     // {
        gen.writeFieldName("aps");  // "aps" :
        gen.writeStartObject();     // {
        gen.writeStringField("alert", value.apns().aps().alert()); // "alert" : " ",
        gen.writeStringField("url", "www.amazon.com");             // "url":"www.amazon.com"
        gen.writeEndObject();       // }
        gen.writeEndObject();       // }
        gen.writeEndObject();       // }
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

```java
SNSNotification snsNotification = new SNSNotification(
    "This is the default message which must be present when publishing a message to a topic. The default message will only be used if a message is not present for one of the notification platforms.",
    new APNS(new APS("Check out these awesome deals!"))
);
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
String json = mapper
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValueAsString(snsNotification);
    
System.out.println(json);
```

*Output:*

```
{
  "default" : "This is the default message which must be present when publishing a message to a topic. The default message will only be used if a message is not present for one of the notification platforms.",
  "APNS" : {
    "aps" : {
      "alert" : "Check out these awesome deals!",
      "url" : "www.amazon.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to output standard JSON. For this API, I need to send JSON encoded into a string field (`"APNS": "{\"aps\": etc}"`).

Comment: @BrendanLong Not sure if I understood correctly, you meant that escaped double quotes `\"` (that are on the right) need to be preserved as `\"`?

Comment: I want the contents of the APNS field to be a string (JSON encoded with the proper escapes), not an object.